# npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angular, npm-install

When i try to install angular/cli using npm install i face these issues continuously. I have set the environmental variables too.

```
C:\Users\rooban>npm install -g @angular/cli
```

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodeJs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
>   npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\rooban\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs  \2019-07-06T15_57_46_319Z-debug.log

```
C:\Users\rooban>npm install -g @angular/cli
```

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodeJs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: it's most likely the common Windows permission problem with `npm`. Maybe this will help: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Try by running the command prompt as administrator.